# OrientDB - Queries with timezone

Tags: sql, orientdb

I need to query orientDB to retrieve data aggregated by day.
E.g.:

```
SELECT OCCURRENCE, COUNT(1) AS NBR_VALUES FROM
(
    SELECT END_PROCESSING.asDate().format('yyyy-MM-dd').asDate().asLong() AS OCCURRENCE
    FROM MY_TABLE 
    WHERE END_PROCESSING >= ? AND END_PROCESSING <= ?
) 
GROUP BY OCCURRENCE
```

However I need to perform this aggregation based on my client timezone (web browser).

Ideally it would be something similar to this:

```
SELECT END_PROCESSING.asDate('Europe/London')
```

Is there a way to achieve this or will I need to do this aggregation on the above layer (Java)?

Comment: I think you should do it in Java, you can also try to open a feature-request on github.

Comment: The problem is that this table may have millions of records and retrieving all "raw" data may be very expensive in terms of performance.
Added a new feature request: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/6951

Comment: You can try using and index

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting per my experience with oracle db.
How about making this a stored procedure? You can return the object with data. Accept the limits as parameters. Get the parameters from upper layer(javascript/java).

I mean something like(Please translate to your db syntax):

```
    FUNCTION get_data(I_time1 TIMESTAMP, I_time2 TIMESTAMP) 
    RETURNS --your object type here---
    IS
    BEGIN
      SELECT OCCURRENCE, COUNT(1) AS NBR_VALUES INTO --your objects here--
     FROM
    (
        SELECT END_PROCESSING.asDate().format('yyyy-MM-dd').asDate().asLong() AS OCCURRENCE
        FROM MY_TABLE 
        WHERE END_PROCESSING >= I_time1 AND END_PROCESSING <= I_time2
    ) 
    GROUP BY OCCURRENCE;
    RETURN --your object--
    ;
    END;
    /
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The problem with your suggestion is that it would return the same result for two requests made from different timezones. The aggregation in the DB must take into account the user's timezone.